# Bootstrap affixed sidebar blocking text

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap to make a page with an affixed sidebar. When I adjust the screen size to a phone, the sidebar does two things:

1. It blocks text behind it (or the text doesn't move under the sidebar)
2. The right side of sidebar doesn't display the border with rounded corners, instead it flushes all the way to the edge of the browser.

How do I get the text to move below the sidebar in phone screen sizes and how can I get the rounded corner border to show?

```
        <div class="row-fluid" style="margin-top:20px;">

            <div id="sub-nav" class="span3">
                <div class="span3 affix" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="200">
                    <div class="well sidebar-nav">
                        <ul class="nav nav-list">
                            <li class="nav-header">Test Sidebar</li>
                            <li><a href="#a">a</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#b">b</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#c">c</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#d">d</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!--/.well -->
                </div><!--/span-->
            </div>

            <div class="span9">
                <div class="page-header">
                    <h1>Test <small>test</small></h1>
                    <em>asdf</em> 
                </div>

                <div id="content">
                    <section id="a">
                    <h4>a</h4>
                    <div style="margin-bottom:500px;"></div>
                    </section>

                    <section id="b">
                    <h4 >b</h4>
                    <div style="margin-bottom:500px;"></div>                        
                    </section>

                    <section id="c">
                    <h4 >c</h4>
                    <div style="margin-bottom:500px;"></div>                        
                    </section>      

                    <section id="d">
                    <h4 >d</h4>
                    <div style="margin-bottom:500px;"></div>                        
                    </section>                      
                </div>

            </div><!--/span-->

        </div><!--/row-->
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that will help is to make the `well` inside the `sidebar-nav`..

```
       <div class="span3 affix" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="200">
          <div class="sidebar-nav">
            <div class="well"> 
              <ul class="nav nav-list">
                <li class="nav-header">Test Sidebar</li>
                <li><a href="#a">a</a></li>
                <li><a href="#b">b</a></li>
                <li><a href="#c">c</a></li>
                <li><a href="#d">d</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div><!--/.well -->
          </div>
        </div><!--/span-->
```

I think you also want to take out the sub-nav `span3` and put the whole thing in a `container-fluid`

### [Here is a Demo](http://bootply.com/61547)